# In Solidity i cant send ethers from _leaser to _owner ( In rent function )

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, remix

there is a set function which allows to address create a Shop or house, The rent function allows to leasers
rent who has house or shops. But i cant send ethers to owners from leaser.

in rent function all requires are working. But i cant send ethers. I am missing some thing. But i couldnt figure it.

// Code starts here .

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Project1 {

```
enum HouseShop {
    House,Shop
}

struct Property {

    address owner;
    string AssetName;
    bool active;
    uint MonthPrice;  
    HouseShop types;
 }

struct contracts {
    address owner;
    string ProportName;
    uint RentPrice;
    uint RentStart;
    uint256 RentEnd;
    address leaser;
}
bool private locked = false;

receive() external payable {}
```

mapping(address => contracts[]) public contractsMap;
mapping(address => Property[]) public PropertyMap;

event setHouseShop1(address indexed _owner,string _AssetName,string types1);
event getRent1(address indexed _leaser,uint256 _HouseShopNumber,string _ProportName,uint256 _RentEnd);
event endRet1(address indexed _address,uint256 _HouseShopNumber );

function setHouseShop (
address _owner,
string memory _AssetName,
string memory types1,uint _amount)
external {
require(msg.sender == _owner,"you are not owner");

```
Property memory property;
property.owner = _owner;
property.AssetName = _AssetName;
property.MonthPrice = _amount;
property.active;
```

if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(types1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("House"))) {
property.types = HouseShop.House;
}else if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(types1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Shop"))) {
property.types = HouseShop.Shop;
} else {
revert("invalid String");
}

```
PropertyMap[msg.sender].push(property);
emit setHouseShop1( _owner,_AssetName,types1);
```

}

```
function getRent (
   address payable _leaser,
   address  payable _owner,
   uint256 _HouseShopNumber,
   string memory _ProportName,
   uint256 _RentEnd,
   uint256 _leaserAmount) 
   external payable {
     require(!locked, "Reentrant call detected!");
     require(_owner != _leaser,"you cant rent yourself");
     require(msg.sender == _leaser,"you are not owner");
     require(checkRent(_owner,_HouseShopNumber) != true,"already rented");
     Property storage property = PropertyMap[ _owner][_HouseShopNumber];
     require(checkRentAmount(_owner,property.MonthPrice) == _leaserAmount,"Invalid Price" );  
     require(msg.sender.balance > _leaserAmount,"You dont have enough ether");    
              
   
      contracts memory _contracts;
       _contracts.leaser = _leaser;
      _contracts.owner = _owner;
      _contracts.ProportName =_ProportName;
      _contracts.RentStart = block.timestamp;
      _contracts.RentEnd = _RentEnd + block.timestamp;
      _contracts.RentPrice = _leaserAmount;
      contractsMap[_owner].push(_contracts);

     locked = true;   

      _owner.transfer(_leaserAmount);    

     locked = false;   


    
      property.active = true;

      emit getRent1(_leaser, _HouseShopNumber, _ProportName, _RentEnd);
}

function endRent(
address _owner,
address _leaser,
uint256 _HouseShopNumber) 
external {
      Property storage property = PropertyMap[_owner][_HouseShopNumber];
      require(msg.sender == contractsMap[_owner][_HouseShopNumber].owner,"You are not owner of this asset");
      require(property.active == true,"Asset is also empty.");
      require(checkTimeRent(_owner, _HouseShopNumber) <= block.timestamp,"Time is not completed.");
      require(_leaser == contractsMap[_owner][_HouseShopNumber].leaser,"leaser is not leaser of this contract"); 
         property.active = false;
         emit endRet1(_leaser, _HouseShopNumber);

}

function removeHouseShop(address _owner,uint _houseShopNumber) external  {
    require(msg.sender == _owner);
    require(PropertyMap[_owner].length > 0,"There is no assets");
    require(checkRent(_owner, _houseShopNumber) == false);

   uint propertyMapLen = PropertyMap[_owner].length;

   if( _houseShopNumber == propertyMapLen -1) {
        PropertyMap[_owner].pop();
   } else { 
   for(uint i = _houseShopNumber;i < propertyMapLen -1;i++) {
    PropertyMap[_owner][i] =  PropertyMap[_owner][i +1];

   }
    PropertyMap[_owner].pop();
   }
 }

function checkRent(address _owner,uint number) internal view returns (bool) {
    Property  storage  property = PropertyMap[_owner][number];
           return property.active;
}

function checkTimeRent(address _owner,uint number) internal view returns (uint) {
    contracts  storage  _contract = contractsMap[_owner][number];
    return _contract.RentEnd;

}
function checkRentAmount(address _owner,uint _HouseShopnumber) internal view returns (uint) {
    Property storage property = PropertyMap[_owner][_HouseShopnumber];
    return property.MonthPrice;
}
```

}